# Scene clip in Video Editor affects the image strip above it

Tags: video-sequence-editor, color-management

In the Video Sequence Editor, I have added a scene and over top I added an image strip.

[image: Image strip over scene]

The image strip is set to 100% opacity and therefore should not be affected by whether the scene is underneath it or not.

However, frame 15 is darker than frame 30.

[image]

What could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I [submitted](https://developer.blender.org/T38344) a false bug report on this issue and a developer, Sergey, explained the problem: Color Management had been turned off.

Color management is on by default, and Sergey suggests not messing with it.  (someone else edited my .blend file)

To re-enable Color Management, go to the Scene tab of the Properties window and under Display Device, select sRGB.

[image: Color Management]

The problem should be gone.  Please see the [bug report](https://developer.blender.org/T38344) for details on why this occurs.